# How can you speed up repeated API calls?

Tags: python, api, for-loop

For a detailed understanding, I have attached a link of file:
[Actual file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16dPVD2sHPQgKn2OD1-UmKuhQMpB0RXc8?usp=sharing)

I have data in the list, that has similar syntax like:

```
i = [a.b>c.d , e.f.g>h.i.j ]
```

e.g. Each element of the list has multiple sub-elements separated by "." and ">".

```
 for i in range(0, len(l)):
    reac={}
    reag={}
    t = l[i].split(">")
    REAC = t[0]
    Reac = REAC.split(".")

    for o in range(len(Reac)):

        reaco = "https://ai.chemistryinthecloud.com/smilies/" + Reac[o]

        respo = requests.get(reaco)
        reac[o] ={"Smile":Reac[o],"Details" :respo.json()}

    if (len(t) != 1):
        REAG = t[1]
        Reag = REAG.split(".")
        for k in range(len(Reag)):

            reagk = "https://ai.chemistryinthecloud.com/smilies/" + Reag[k]
            repo = requests.get(reagk)
            reag[k] = {"Smile": Reag[k], "Details" :repo.json()}
        res = {"Reactants": list(reac.values()), "Reagents": list(reag.values())}
        boo.append(res)
    else:
        res = {"Reactants": list(reac.values()), "Reagents": "No reagents"}
        boo.append(res)
```

We have separated all the elements and for each element, we are calling 3rd party API. That consumes too much time.

Is there any way to reduce this time and optimize for the loop?

It takes around 1 minute to respond. We want to optimize to 5-10 seconds.

Comment: If you want to reduce the number of API calls you probably can only do so by caching the results (e.g. do not call for `K` twice), and by running in parallel (threads are fine).  Your loops almost certainly have no impact on anything.

Comment: But the problem is time complexity. It has MxN time complexity and it takes extra time for API calling as well. We want to reduce it.

Comment: Can you help with thread implementation?

Comment: You **do not** have `O(m*n)` complexity, you have `O(k)` complexity.  You do an api call for each element in the string, the splits and loops have "literally" zero impact.  My proposal is to do an api call, once, for each unique element in the string in parallel, which is the fastest you can make it on your end.  If you persist the cache it will even make your calculation instantaneous.

Comment: Can you help me with code @cireo

Comment: I tried to find a good question on python caching api requests but didn't find one to point you to.  I might ask and answer that question later tonight or tomorrow so you can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this instead.  I changed the format of your output because it made things unnecessisarily complicated, and removed a lot of non-pythonic things you were doing.  The second time you run should be instantaneous, and the first time should be much faster if you have repeated values across equations or sides of the reaction.

```
# pip install cachetools diskcache
from cachetools import cached
from diskcache import Cache

BASE_URL = "https://ai.chemistryinthecloud.com/smilies/"
CACHEDIR = "api_cache"

@cached(cache=Cache(CACHEDIR))
def get_similies(value):
    return requests.get(BASE_URL + value).json()


def parse_eq(eq):
    reac, _, reag = (set(v.split(".")) for v in eq.partition(">"))
    return {
        "reactants": {i: get_similies(i) for i in reac},
        "reagents": {i: get_similies(i) for i in reag}
    }

result = [parse_eq(eq) for eq in eqs]
```

Comment: It is working but while value is empty in list at that time code was broken any suggestions on that?

Comment: Here is my effort  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1c7MAHQlJR7BohcdBmmHgKd6P6y84SCDQ#scrollTo=6UFtlSr2qSnB]

Comment: rdkit took more than one try to install, so I'm not going to run the code.  can you either open a new question for your new problem, or provide information?  "code was broken" doesn't mean anything

Comment: Ok i will make new question for that @Cireo